# Real part of a product?

Tags: complex-numbers

We have:
$$
\Re\{Ae^{i\phi}e^{i\omega}\}=\Re\{Ae^{i(\phi+\omega)}\}=A\cos(\phi+\omega)
$$
But why does the following not give the same the answer:
\begin{align}
\Re\{Ae^{i\phi}e^{i\omega}\}
&=A\Re\{e^{i\phi}e^{i\omega}\}\\
&=A\Re\{e^{i\phi}\}\Re\{e^{i\omega}\}\\
&=A\cos(\phi)\cos(\omega) \quad ?
\end{align}

Comment: $\Re(ab)\ne\Re(a)\Re(b)$.

Answer (score 7):

You made the assumption in the penultimate line that the real part of a product is a product of the real parts. But that's simply not true. Remember the definition for complex multiplication in rectangular coordinates?

Say let us have $w=a+ib$ and $z=p+iq$, then $$\Re(wz)=ap-bq\neq{ap}=\Re(w)\Re(z)$$ as you assumed.

Answer (score 3):

As @CaveJohnson wrote in a comment, the real part of a complex number is not a multiplicative function. An easy counter-example would be

$$\Re(i)\Re(i)=0\neq-1=\Re(i^2)$$

Hence, only your **first** calculation is correct.

**EDIT:** You can calculate directly and see that in fact, if $z_{1}=a+bi$ and $z_{2}=c+di$, then

$$\Re\left(z_{1}z_{2}\right)=\Re\Big((ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i\Big)=ac-bd=\Re(z_{1})\Re(z_{2})-\color{red}{\Im(z_{1})\Im(z_{2})}$$

Comment: Hi! I checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number, but I couldn't find any rule why it is wrong?

Comment: @JDoeDoe Why do you assume it's true? Wikipedia doesn't list this as a statement.

Comment: @JDoeDoe You're into a wrong way of thinking. In mathematics, only what _can_ be _proved_ is considered true; what has _not_ yet been _disproved_ is only a conjecture. Let alone the fact that it has been disproved in this answer. For an easy example, can you find any source claiming $192\times 364=69886$ is wrong? Does this mean that it is a correct equality?